# Delete from table with variables not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to delete from my table this is the function,

```
function deleteFromTable($table, $file_upload_id, $dbh) {
    $deleteTable = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE upload_id = ?");
    $deleteTable->execute(array($file_upload_id));
    $deleted = $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    print_r($deleted);exit;
}
deleteFromTable('reimbursment_id', '76', $dbh);
```

I'm getting no error and its not removing anything from my table; But when I tried to do without the variables it works perfectly, whats wrong with this code?

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine, the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Do you *know* that you're passing in the correct variable?

Comment: @Blowski Yes I know, I even printed out perfectly in the function.

Comment: I gave it a shot. Have a nice day...

Comment: @Giovanni Sferro The problem was I passed the `$file_upload_id` as an array two times, now it works for me too, thanks for everyone for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Just try something like this. Dont think prepare likes variables

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM :table WHERE id = :id');
$sth->execute(array(':table' => $table, ':id' => $file_upload_id));
```

If this done work try to echo out the sql and try it in phpmyadmin or mysql terminal if you got one.